# Scala - Use of .indexOf() and .indexWhere()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, indexof

I have a tuple like the following:

```
(Age, List(19,17,11,3,2))
```

and I would like to get the position of the first element where their position in the list is greater than their value. To do this I tried to use .indexOf() and .indexWhere() but I probably can't find exactly the right syntax and so I keep getting:

> value indexWhere is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String,
>   Iterable[Int])]

My code so far is:

```
val test =("Age", List(19,17,11,3,2))
test.indexWhere(_.2(_)<=_.2(_).indexOf(_.2(_)) )
```

I also searched the documentation here with no result: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

Comment: The code you pasted does not correlate to the error you've described: the error means that you're trying to call `indexWhere` on a `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` which does not have such a method. `RDD` is an abstraction for a _distributed_ collection, and it _not_ part of Scala's collection library, so don't expect every collection library method to belong to it.

Comment: Can I overcome this somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform this for *each element in an RDD*, you can use RDD's `mapValues` (which would only map the right-hand-side of the tuple) and pass a function that uses `indexWhere`:

```
rdd.mapValues(_.zipWithIndex.indexWhere { case (v, i) => i+1 > v} + 1)
```

Notes:

- Your example seems wrong, if you want the *last* matching item it should be 5 (position of 2) and not 4
- You did not define what should be done when no item matches your condition, e.g. for `List(0,0,0)` - in this case the result would be 0 but not sure that's what you need

Comment: Thanks for the help! :) About the example you are right.. I meant the first position where the condition holds!

Comment: If this answers your question - please accept the answer; If not - please clarify how so. Otherwise - other users won't be able to help you or know if you even need it.